# SCNPhysicsBody applyTorque reverse

Tags: ios, scenekit, arkit

I have a physics body node on which I apply an angular force like the follow:

```
node.physicsBody?.applyTorque(SCNVector4(x: 0, y: 0, z: 1, w: 0.1), impulse: true)
```

but after an arbitrary time I want to stop the torque effect and apply the reverse effect **to restore the original node position**. What is the proper way to do this?

I can't simply reverse the SCNVector values because the first torque may has been interrupted before its effect has been completed.

Comment: It's not an answer, but an impulsive way is node.physicsBody?.applyTorque(SCNVector4(x: 0, y: 0, z: 1, w: -0.1), impulse: true), let it reverse the same time.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But I need to reverse multiple applyTorque applied on different axis and in sequence.
In other words I always have to bring back the character at its original position after it has been moved with many applyTorque applications.

Comment: Then apply with reversed order one by one.  Sometime it's just not precise.

Comment: What if the user moves the character for a long time (that could be for example 30 seconds...)? I will probably have to reverse bilions of applyTorque!
I'm looking for a property in the node or another tecnique that will gives me its angular rotation. Unfortunately character.presentationNode.rotation doesn't return right values, at least for my purposes.

Comment: There are some numbers as the records from the initial position.